# is python list comprehension possible inside a for loop?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, rhino3d

consider this python list comprehension code in Rhino v.5 below:

```
for j in range(1,3):
    globals()["objlist" + str(j)] = [rs.OrientObject(obj, [rs.PointCoordinates(x) for x in objlist[1:4]], [rs.PointCoordinates(x) for x in objlist[1+ j*3:4+ j*3]], 1) for obj in objlist]
```

as a lot of you will not know rhinoscriptsyntax commands which i'm calling here:

```
rs.OrientObject  and rs.PointCoordinates
```

I hope you can read the rest syntax, as the problem is in the list comprehension not in rhinoscriptsyntax.

what i'm failing to get to work is the second 'j' inside the list slicing code of:

```
objlist[1+ j*3:4+ j*3]
```

I only get the results of this for j=1 but not for j=2 although i'm using a j in a loop in range(1,3)

is the 'for j in range(1,3)' not working at all in this case, is it working only for the left side of the '=' where i'm using it for the 'objlist + str(j)' or it shouldn't be used at all with list comprehension and I should find a way to rewrite everything with list comprehension?

p.s. even if I resolved the globals() issue with dictionaries, I would still need the j in order to slice the lists on different ranges on every iteration.

Comment: This code looks OK to me. Your problem is not in list comprehensions. You could try to localize the problem and provide code that we can actually test instead of relying on your words.

Comment: If you're having a problem with the list comprehensions, pull them out of the larger expression and test them each individually, find out which one is not working, then figure out how to give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the same problem so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that part is working fine:

```
>>> objlist = range(10)
>>> for j in range(1,3):
...   print objlist[1+ j*3:4+ j*3]
... 
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Note that, due to the way you've written the loop, the case with `j` equal to `1` will apply only to your variable `objlist1`, and the case with `j` equal to `2` will apply only to your variable `objlist2`.  Is that what's confusing you?

I think you should also refactor this, it's better to use an explicit loop than try to be clever with list comprehensions all the time if the comprehension is going to be such a long line.  And, yes, you should be using a dictionary here rather than mucking with `globals()` but I guess you already know that.

Comment: props for mentioning a refactor and not messing with globals

Comment: trying to solve list comprehension problem first before I go to resolve the dictionary problem. one step at a time! 
my idea was to have everything in list comprehension style. still I wrote the loop just like you say, objlist1 gets the case of j=1 and objlist2 only the case of j=2.

my new question is: no matter how many list comprehensions you have inside another list comprehension, the 'j' would always be either 1 or 2 here? or is it something a recursive function?

Comment: Yes, the j will always be 1 or 2 here, because you are only looping over j at the outermost level.

Comment: The code is equivalent to `objlist1 = [rs.OrientObject(obj, [rs.PointCoordinates(x) for x in objlist[1:4]], [rs.PointCoordinates(x) for x in objlist[4:7] ], 1) for obj in objlist];` 
`objlist2 = [rs.OrientObject(obj, [rs.PointCoordinates(x) for x in objlist[1:4]], [rs.PointCoordinates(x) for x in objlist[7:10]], 1) for obj in objlist]`